# iFrame get focus and lost focus event with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a iFrame which is showing some input fields. Now I need to show some message when someone edit the input fields and disappear the message when someone done with the editing.

**Note**: Input fields can't be accessible from Javascript (no js events/css anything)

Any idea for this problem?

**Scenario**:
Actually, I have a recording system, which records everything on the page. but I want to pause the recording when I entered in the iFrame Area and resume again, once user are outside the iFrame. The iFrame authority restricted iFrame content access.

**Solution**

> So far according to the discussion and my analysis, If I am unable to
>   access the content of iFrame, it's not possible to attach any JS event
>   to iFrame

Comment: Um, if you can not access the iframe with Javascript, than there is really nothing you can do.

Comment: @epascarello actually, I can't access content of the iFrame, but I can access the iframe element.

Comment: Does not matter, if you can not access the content inside, than you can not listen to anything. This is assuming the iframe is a different domain. If you have control of the page inside the iframe there can be a solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand that one. But Is there any hack for that?

Comment: No, that is what the same origin policy is protecting us from.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try what else I can try. I will update once I have the solutions...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121578/discussion-between-m-m-h-masud-and-epascarello).